# Usage of "along the way"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct ?

a: Where are you going John?
b: I am going to the front office.
a: Have Marry call me back ,while being there. Please.

Comment: Confused by the title of this topic and the example you provided. Did you want to know how 'along the way' is used? It doesn't appear in your example at all and wouldn't be used here.

Comment: -1 because your example doesn't include the phrase you said you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

No. Here are two correct ways:

Have Marry call me back, while you're there, please.

While you're there, have Marry call me back, please.

Do you mean *Mary* instead of *Marry*? Do you mean *return my call* when you write *call me back*?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have written "while being .." because

Comment: 'Call me back' would be perfectly acceptable in British English, and would be synonymous with 'return my call'

Comment: How about that sentence ? You have Mary call me, while being there.

Comment: It is not grammatical, and the intended meaning is unclear. My guess is that you want to say, *While you're there, tell her to call me back.*